# maxpooling error in Tenssoflow ;Check failed: dnnPoolingCreateForward_F32(.<parameter list>.) == E_SUCCESS (-127 vs. 0)

Tags: tensorflow, max-pooling

I am learning tesnorflow from this blog: 
http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

The code i am running is :
https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/train.py

I have installed tensorflow from sourcse in a virtual enviroment,in CPU only enviroment using followinbg bazel build command: bazel build --config=mkl ...

here is the exact error:

"2018-01-16 03:15:27.783040: F tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_maxpooling_op.cc:157] Check failed: dnnPoolingCreateForward_F32( &prim_pooling_fwd, primAttr, algorithm, lt_user_input, params.kernel_size, params.kernel_stride, params.in_offset, dnnBorderZerosAsymm) == E_SUCCESS (-127 vs. 0)
Aborted
"

I have debugged error to the line where sess.run is written, i have beleived it has something to do it mkl_maxpooling, as i had installed tensorflow with mkl optimization of INTEL cpu's

Comment: Can you clarify your question and post your code?

Comment: I am learning tesnorflow from this blog: http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/    , the code i am running is : https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/train.py

Comment: Add relevant informations to the question, please

Answer (score 1):

Given below are the steps that I followed:

1. Build tensorflow 1.4 from source with mkl as mentioned in the question
2. Cloned the git repo "https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf.git"
3. Ran "python train.py" from "cnn-text-classification-tf" directory(created from git clone)

Code ran without any errors. So it seems like the tensorflow was not properly built from the source. Please confirm that there were no errors while building tensorflow from source.

Comment: @rakeshKM Did you try building same version (1.4) of tensorflow from source ? Also, please confirm if you used the below mentioned commands, while building tensorflow from source:

Comment: @rakeshKM Did you try building same version (1.4) of tensorflow from source ? Also, please confirm if you used the below mentioned commands, while building tensorflow from source:`./configure`   `bazel build --config=mkl -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`   `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`  `pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/<NAME_TENSORFLOW_WHEEL_CREATED>`